# Как сохранить app в arr архив?

Tags: android

Почему для модуля можно создвть `arr` a для app только `apk`? В чем вообще отличие app от модуля я не вижу в gradle разницы. Но Android Studio как-то их отличает...

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.2"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.android.myapplication"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    productFlavors {
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.1'
}
```

.

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.library'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.2"

    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.1'
}
```

Comment: разница в первой строчке конфига gradle

Comment: Хм...Вы правы. Я почему-то придал этому другое значение... Можно ли как-то сделать `arr` с `application`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Формат aar - это формат упаковки [android-библиотеки](http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/aar-format) (Android Library Format)/ Естественно, что сохранить в этот формат можно библиотеку, а не приложение.

О типе получаемого на выходе файла говорит строка `apply plugin`, где соответственно указывается библиотека это (library) или приложение (application)

Вы можете сделать из своего приложения библиотеку (заменить `apply plugin: 'com.android.application'` на `apply plugin: 'com.android.library'`) и собрать ее в aar-формат

Answer (score 3):

Первая же строка отличается:

`apply plugin: 'com.android.library'` для модуля

и

`apply plugin: 'com.android.application'` для приложения.

Comment: Даниэль, надо было написать "Первая строчка Карл! Первая строчка!" :)